# Getting Page Fedstep1 does not exist error

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom

I am try to create Wizard for custom object but am getting  Fedstep1 does not exist error

Here is my code

```
public class Pageniation {
public FeedbackFrom__c Fed{get;set;}

 public FeedbackFrom__c getFed() {
      if(Fed== null) Fed = new FeedbackFrom__c();
      return Fed;
   }
    public PageReference step1() {
      return Page.Fedstep1;
   }

   public PageReference step2() {
      return Page.Fedstep2;
   }

   public PageReference step3() {
      return Page.Fedstep3;
   }
 public PageReference cancel() {
            PageReference FeedbackPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(Fed).view();
            FeedbackPage.setRedirect(true);
            return FeedbackPage; 
    }
public PageReference save() {

PageReference FeedbackPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(Fed).view();
      FeedbackPage.setRedirect(true);

      return FeedbackPage;
   }

}
```

How can i retrieve from this.

Comment: r u sure those pages FedStep1, FedStep2, FedStep3 exist in your org ?

Comment: i am not sure vamsi i am new to SFDC how can i achieve this..??? where i need to create this steps...

Comment: Hi Vamsi Now i have creted the Vf Pages By using FedStep1, FedStep2, FedStep3 this name its working fine Now